# Displaying node reference select list as ordered menu list

Tags: views, routes, nodes

I want to display the Node Reference Select List (usually a long list of nodes, unordered and generally quite long) as an ordered bunch of nodes, that replicate the structure of the menu system.

The whole idea, is for a user to be able to choose another Node, but as there are so many nodes already on the website - it can be difficult to find the correct one in the select list. I have attached a screenshot to show a random example of how I would like this to look. This is just a quick mock-up image that I hope can be achievable.

The new "menu style" select list makes it easier to find the particular nodes you want, as they mirror the menu system of the website.

[image]

I looked into using Views to replicate the structure of the menu in Drupal, but this doesn't seem possible either. If this was possible, I could simple use the "Advanced - nodes that can be referenced" and just list out the pages by the menu with the order - but it doesn't look possible to integrate Views and the drupal menu system.

Any help would be excellent with this. Thanks, Garry.

Answer (score 1):

You can use view to display all node you want and use expose filter to search for a specific node
or to display as tree
I guess there is a module to display taxonomy as a tree reference to make it like parent and child
so you can convert your node to be taxonomy to easy make it as a tree or change the module structure to display nodes

Comment: I'm not using taxonomy and won't be implementing it either as CCK is much better.

Comment: look I think that taxonomy is a perfect solution to parent child relation and sure cck is much better, try to use draggable view I don't know if it can help

Answer (score 1):

Using a view on the reference field and:

I have used

http://drupal.org/project/views_hierarchy

or views tree

http://drupal.org/project/views_tree

Could help you.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the suggestions are for the display of hierarchy on the front end, however this requirement is to be able to get that on a Reference view, to be used for selecting a value in a nodereference field.

My solution was the following, which is dependent on path aliases reflecting the menu structure:

1. On the reference view add the field "Content: Path"
2. Install the module [Views PHP](http://drupal.org/project/views_php) or do a template override
3. Output the path of the node using the Global: PHP field like that below

   nid);
       print substr($static, 0, strrpos($static, '/')).' - '. $row->title;
   ?>
   The above giving you a list of node titles prepended by the menu path.